# Bash script Error: (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, bc

My bash script is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
wc=(5000 10000 20000 50000);
for r2 in {0.01 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.95};
do
  for i in {0..3};
  do

    rr=$(echo "${r2} * 100" | bc)
    ww=$(echo "${wc[$i]} / ${rr}" | bc)
    echo $ww

  done
done
```

However, I get the error message `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`.

Do you have any idea to address this issue? Thank you in advance!

The equivalent R code is the following

```
wc <- c(50,100,200,500)
for(k in c(0.01,0.1,0.4,0.7,0.95)){
   for(i in 1:4){
      
       ww <- floor(wc[i]/k)
       print(ww)
   }

}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is a `bc` error, not a bash error -- different languages with different syntax. If you want to know what operations bash is telling `bc` to do, using `set -x` to enable tracing would be a good place to start, and would make the bug very clear (you'd see bash telling bc to calculate with `{0.01` as a number, with the `{` as part of its value, f/e).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Thank you for pointing out the error and your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need commas in the brace expression:

```
for r2 in {0.01,0.1,0.4,0.7,0.95};
```

Otherwise, you are simply iterating over the sequence `{0.01`, `0.1`, ..., `0.95}`.

There's really no need for a brace expression anyway:

```
for r2 in 0.01 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.95;
```